# Получить id последнего div

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить `id` последнего `div` в котором нет класса `dis` и дочерний `input` является `checked`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = $("#content .item").not(".dis").last().children("input:checked").attr("id");
  console.log(id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="item" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="4">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="item dis" id="5">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#content .item:not(.dis) input:checked').last().closest('.item').attr("id")`

Comment: `$('#content .item:not(.dis):has(input:checked)').last().attr('id')`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = $("#content .item").not(".dis").find("input:checked").last().closest('.item').attr("id");
  console.log(id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="item" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="3">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="4">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="item dis" id="5">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
</div>
```